# How to give an Android app its own SE (Android) context

Tags: android, selinux

We roll our own Android dist. We'd like to give some non-system apps heightened privileges.

I understand using the `typebounds` rule I can create a new type that is bounded by some other type. So I did like:

```
typebounds system_app my_app;
```

To give `my_app` the same access control as `system_app`. Later I can add rules to deny `my_app` certain things but that's not my immediate concern.

What I'm unclear about is how to define the type `my_app` and associate it with a particular app. I found some examples that looked like this,

```
user=system seinfo=platform name=com.qualcomm.qti.auth.fidocryptoservice domain=qsee_svc_app type=qsee_svc_app_data_file
```

So in my case I tried this:

```
user=_app seinfo=platform name=com.myapp type=my_app domain=my_app levelFrom=user
```

but after boot, `ps -aZ` still shows my app (com.myapp) running in the context untrusted app:

```
u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 u0_a93    4154  2339  1726288 68944 SyS_epoll_ 7f99f257b8 S com.myapp
```

Why is this?